# What are some popular web media players out there? Also, are they able to support .mpeg or .avi files?

Tags: javascript, html, media-player

I'm looking for a media player to implement into my website. What are some of the popular options out there today? I need the media player to play video specifically .mpeg, .mpeg4 or .avi.

Is that possible or will I have to convert .avi/.mpeg to .wma (I found Yahoo web media player and it seems alright besides the fact that I have to convert all my video files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html 
here is a link that tells you all about video formats for websites and browser compatibility